# Não é possível alterar campo no php quando o id não é igual a 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update, xampp

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer uma alteração no meu banco de dados através do php, porém ao clicar no de "alterar" ele só permite se o código for igual a 1, eu já coloquei no html para enviar o id assim que clicamos em "alterar" porém ele só puxa a página caso o código seja igual a 1, segue abaixo meu código:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$nome = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$idfornec = $_GET['idfornec'];

?>

<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$senha = "";
$banco = "visaosystem";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $senha) or die (mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco) or die (mysql_error());

$selectfornec = ("SELECT fornecedor.razaosocial, fornecedor.nomefantasia, fornecedor.cnpj, fornecedor.ie, fornecedor.ativo, contatofornec.telefone1, contatofornec.telefone2, 
contatofornec.celular, contatofornec.email, enderecofornec.cep, enderecofornec.logradouro, enderecofornec.bairro, enderecofornec.municipio, enderecofornec.cidade, enderecofornec.uf, enderecofornec.numero, enderecofornec.complemento FROM fornecedor
INNER JOIN contatofornec ON (fornecedor.idfornec = contatofornec.idcontatofornec) INNER JOIN enderecofornec ON (fornecedor.idfornec = enderecofornec.idenderecofornec) WHERE fornecedor.idfornec = '$idfornec'") or die(mysqli_error());


$dadosfornec = $conexao->query($selectfornec);


        while ($linha = $dadosfornec->fetch_assoc()) {
        $razaosocial = $linha["razaosocial"];
        $nomefantasia = $linha["nomefantasia"];
        $cnpj = $linha["cnpj"];
        $ie = $linha["ie"];
        $ativo = $linha["ativo"];
        $primeironum = $linha["telefone1"];
        $segundonu = $linha["telefone2"];
        $celular = $linha["celular"];
        $email = $linha["email"];
        $cep = $linha["cep"];
        $endereco = $linha["logradouro"];
        $bairro = $linha["bairro"];
        $municipio = $linha["municipio"];
        $cidade = $linha["cidade"];
        $uf = $linha["uf"];
        $numero = $linha["numero"];
        $complemento = $linha["complemento"];
?>
```

Comment: O erro pode estar nesse $idFornec, dê um print nele apenas.